# I'm having trouble understanding the purpose and need to use XML

Tags: xml, database

Basically, why use xml?  I mean I know its for structering data, but still not seeing it's real-world benefits?  Like with databases for a website, why not just take the user input directly instead of from and xml file first?  I'm just not seeing the point.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Note that this is a site for programming questions *that can be correctly answered*. Asking "what is your opinion on XML?" is likely to provoke an entirely subjective discussion on the lines of "XML is the spawn of the devil" vs "XML is the greatest thing since sliced bread".

Comment: I'm not familiar with this "directly" format. How does communicate the contents of a shelf, grouped by drawers, using this "directly" format? One of the advantage of XML over coming up with a brand new format is that there exists good tools for working with XML.

Comment: The question is not "What is your opinion on XML ?", but "Can you give me one or more use case where XML is useful" ? This looks like a valid question to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to exchanges datas between two systems for example, you may need structured, human-readable datas.